# Laravel API Route 404 on Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a laravel 8 application deployed on Azure App Service, this is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot/public; # changed for Laravel
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name doctors-portal-api.azurewebsites.net;

    location / {            
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # changed for Laravel
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

And this is my routes_public.php file:

```
<?php

use App\Api\Doctor\DoctorApiController;


Route::post('doctors/register', [DoctorApiController::class, 'register'])->name('doctors.register');
Route::get('doctors/hospitals', [DoctorApiController::class, 'hospitals'])->name('doctors.hospitals');
Route::get('doctors/{md_id}', [DoctorApiController::class, 'show'])->name('doctors.show');
Route::get('doctors/user/{user_id}', [DoctorApiController::class, 'show_by_user_id'])->name('doctors.show_by_user_id');
Route::get('doctors', [DoctorApiController::class, 'index'])->name('doctors.index');
```

With this setup, I am able to access these API routes without issues:
https://doctors-portal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/doctors
https://doctors-portal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/files

However, the API routes below give an error: 404 Not Found nginx/1.22.1

https://doctors-portal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/doctors/hospitals
https://doctors-portal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/file/upload

What do I need to do to fix it?

**When I run my laravel application locally, all of the API urls work fine on localhost.**

Comment: Not sure about the 404 issue but `doctors/user/{user_id}` should be listed before `doctors/{md_id}`. Also, I don't see a route for `/files` or `/file` so that could be getting caught by `doctors/{md_id}`, which is probably why that one isn't working.

Comment: @Raven I hope this document will help you https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue a couple of hours ago. My laravel 10 application was working as expected and suddendly stopped working (I did not deploy a new version).

I realized that nginx version changed to 1.24 so you can check this part.

What worked for me was to have the same config file you have in /etc/nginx/sites-available in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

You could try copy this file like this:

```
cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Considering default is the filename of your config you mentioned.

Also you could make a symbolic link if you want

```
ln -s sites-available/default sites-enabled/default
```

You may have to remove sites-enabled/default before doing the link

Hope this works for you

Comment: Exactly what I need! I just also noticed and realized that. Thanks for answering!